# Display different icon on ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, icons

I have a xml file name "list_row.xml", this was load in a listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_one"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
/>
```

I use a function to load data from my table and fill in my "list_row.xml" file

```
private void fillData() {       
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    String[] from = new String[]{ ListDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID,
            ListDbAdapter.KEY_ICON, ListDbAdapter.KEY_LABEL };
    int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.id, R.id.icon, R.id.label };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, c, from, to );     
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My question is how can I check the icon value to set the icon display on my listview (my data have to icon: icon_one, icon_two). Can someone help me with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html):

> Binding occurs in two phases. First,
>   if a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder is
>   available,
>   setViewValue(android.view.View,
>   android.database.Cursor, int)  is
>   invoked. If the returned value is
>   true, binding has occured. If the
>   returned value is false and the view
>   to bind is a TextView,
>   setViewText(TextView, String) is
>   invoked. If the returned value is
>   false and the view to bind is an
>   ImageView, setViewImage(ImageView,
>   String) is invoked.

So, override `setViewImage()` and manually associate your icon with the ImageView. Or, override `newView()` and `bindView()` and manually bind your whole rows.

Comment: Why I find it tough to understand?